# Replace using RegEx in notepad++

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I would like to replace all names in an XML file tagged by  with let's say xyz. In other words, replace everything (including whitespace) between the tags. What am I doing wrong?

```
Search: (<name>)(.*)(</name>)
Replace: \1xyz\3
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you try it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to [parse XML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

However, what you are doing wrong anyway is using a greedy repetition. This will go all the way from the first `<name>` to the very last `</name>` (even if they do not belong together), because the `.*` will try to consume as much as possible while still fulfilling the match condition.. Use this instead:

```
Search: (<name>).*?(</name>)
Replace: \1xyz\2
```

Or to be on the safe side you can also escape the `<` and `>`, since they are meta-characters in some specific cases (not in this one though):

```
Search: (\<name\>).*?(\</name\>)
Replace: \1xyz\2
```

In both cases, this makes the `.*` ungreedy, i.e. it will consume as little as possible.

And make sure you upgrade to Notepad++ 6, because before that there were a few issues with Notepad++'s regex engine.

Lastly, as hoombar pointed out in a comment `.` by default matches every character **except** line break characters. In Notepadd++ you can change this behavior by ticking the `. matches newline` checkbox.

Comment: you might also want to check the box ". matches new line"

Comment: I generally escape the `<>` to prevent unexpected behaviour `\<\>`

Comment: @Ariaan It's probably a matter of taste (I usually prefer the readability), and would only differ inside a named capturing group, wouldn't it?

Comment: @m.buettner You're correct, but I'd prefer to be prepared for reuse in larger regular expressions, in case you'd need to extend your expression. I don't think it's a bad habit when writing complicated expressions.