# Notepad++ Find/Replace with wildcard?

Tags: xml, replace, notepad++

I have a huge xml file, where i need to find and replace some parts. In total it occurs around 2100 times, so i hoped i could solve this by using the advanced tools in Notepad++.
It doesnt have to be notepad++, so if there is another solution, im helped as well.

The find occurrence looks like this:

```
        <condition test="contains" flags="90">
          <category>
            <name internal="Type">Type</name>
          </category>
          <property>
            <name internal="parameter">Code</name>
          </property>
          <value>
            <data type="wstring">21.12</data>
          </value>
        </condition>
```

Everything is consistent, except for the number in the data part `21.12`
This number is different in all the 2100 cases.

So i want to Find and replace, but ise that number as some kind of wildcard that is used in the find AND replace.
The part where i have to find works as it should be with regex ([Replace using RegEx in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195217/replace-using-regex-in-notepad) ). But i am not able to paste the part of the regex.

So in short, if my code looks like this:

```
<code>6</code>
<code>7</code>
<code>8</code>
```

i want to find/replace to make it look like this:

```
<code>6</code>
<extraCode>6</extraCode>
<code>7</code>
<extraCode>7</extraCode>
<code>8</code>
<extraCode>8</extraCode>
```

Would this be possible, of would i need some other software, or make some C# script to do this?

Comment: Are all numbers integer or float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answers directly to the second part of your question.  You may try the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
<code>(\d+)</code>
```

**Replace:**

```
<code>$1</code>\n<extraCode>$1</extraCode>
```

If this does not meet your requirements, then you should have phrased your question differently.

Note: If the contents of the `<code>` tags could be something besides numbers, then match on this pattern:

```
<code>([^<]+)</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<data type="wstring">(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)</data>`
- Replace with: `$0\n<extraCode>$1</extraCode>`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(         : start group 1
  \d+     : 1 or more digits
  (?:     : start non capture group
    \.    : a dot
    \d+   : 1 or more digits
  )?      : end group, optional
)         : end group 1
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          : the whole match
\n          : a linebreak, you could use \r\n

$1          : content of group 1 (ie. the value)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
    <condition test="contains" flags="90">
      <category>
        <name internal="Type">Type</name>
      </category>
      <property>
        <name internal="parameter">Code</name>
      </property>
      <value>
        <data type="wstring">21.12</data>
<extraCode>21.12</extraCode>
      </value>
    </condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$0\n<extraCode>$1<extraCode>` for replace. Therefore you would need to find like this: `<code>(\d+)<code>` you can expand this if needed by adding more subgroups to match.

EDIT: Seems like I was too slow ;)